The merge process was unable to deliver the snapshot to the Subscriber
I am setting up replication on SQL Server and I get this error, if I open the replication monitor there is this error, if I open the agent logs, there is also this error. What else can I check?

No subscription is on this publication or article. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 14050)
Get help: http://help/14050


The merge process was unable to deliver the snapshot to the Subscriber. If using Web synchronization, the merge process may have been unable to create or write to the message file. When troubleshooting, restart the synchronization with verbose history logging and specify an output file to which to write. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147201001)

Snapshot is created, publisher and subscriber servers are pinged and accessible by name, there is enough disk space.
I looked at the log file located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\COM and this is our message:
DatabaseReconciler            , 2024/10/03 05:24:23.796, 8636, 20623,  S2, INFO: Session Highlights: ADD_INITIAL_PUBLICATION, SCHEMA_CHANGES, FAIL, PUB_INSERTS,
DatabaseReconciler            , 2024/10/03 05:25:23.812, 8636, 13291,  S2, INFO: Reading profile: AgentID:6, AgentType:4, ProfileName:
replrec!FillErrorInfo         , 2024/10/03 05:25:40.015, 8636, 20503,  S1, ERROR: ErrNo = 0x80045005, ErrSrc = , ErrType = 9, ErrStr = The subscription to publication 'sync' could not be verified. Ensure that all Merge Agent command line parameters are specified correctly and that the subscription is correctly configured. If the Publisher no longer has information about this subscription, drop and recreate the subscription.
DatabaseReconciler            , 2024/10/03 05:25:40.031, 8636, 20616,  S2, :T:,110,20,643,,,,,,,
I deleted and created a subscriber, but it didn't solve the problem.
